# calculate effect size from regression table

Tags: chi-squared-test, statistical-power, effect-size, cohens-d, wald-test

I am working on power analysis for a project. I want to benchmark effect size from another study. How can I find the effect size (Cohen's d) just by looking at the regression table below? For instance, how would you calculate the effect size from the regression table below:

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------
                      (1)                                         
                    outcome                                      
----------------------------------------------------------------------
treatment            .13***       (.03)
var1                -.07*         (.03)
_cons               -.11**        (.04)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
standard error in parentheses
* p<0.05, ** p<0.01, *** p<0.001
R2                   .24
N                    452                                           
----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Do you think this formula is useful? Cohen's d = t-value / √N
In this case, the effect size of variable treatment is: (0.13/0.03) / √452 = 0.204. Thus, the effect size overall is low. Do you think this is a satisfactory way to do it?

Alternatively, if I wanted to find the cohen's f or eta squared, what additional information would you need?

Best,

Comment: I don't think you can, without more information.

Comment: What else would you need?

Comment: N, variance (or SD) of the outcome.

Comment: And do you want effect size for the whole model or for a specific predictor estimate?

Comment: Just for the specific predictor estimate

Comment: Do you think this formula is useful? Cohen's d = t-value / √N

Comment: In this case, the effect size of variable treatment is: (0.13/0.03) / √452 = 0.204. Thus, the effect size overall is low. Do you think this is a satisfactory way to do it?

Comment: Please add additional info as an edit to the post, and not only as comments! Comments are easily overseen and can be removed!